# md5sum returns a different hash value than online hash generators

Tags: linux, cryptography

On suse10

```
md5sum myname
```

gives md5 hash as `49b0939cb2db9d21b038b7f7d453cd5d`.

The file myname contains string "ravi"

while some of the online md5 hash generators for the same string seem to give a different hash

http://md5-encryption.com/
http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php

They spit out the hash for "ravi" as `63dd3e154ca6d948fc380fa576343ba6`

Why is there a difference in md5sum for the same string "ravi"?

Comment: Does your file include a new line or not?

Answer (score 31):

If you look at your file `myname`, you will probably find that it contains extra characters e.g.

```
od -x myname
0000000 6172 6976 000a
0000005
```

Note the `000a` at the end of line 1. When you type `ravi` into the online form you are not entering the `000a` as well so the md5sums are different.

You can see the effect of this like so

```
echo ravi | od -x 
0000000 6172 6976 000a

echo ravi | md5sum 
49b0939cb2db9d21b038b7f7d453cd5d  -
```

The answers are the same as for you file.

```
echo -n ravi | od -x 
0000000 6172 6976

echo -n ravi | md5sum
63dd3e154ca6d948fc380fa576343ba6  -
```

The results are the same as the online form.

Comment: +1 for echo -n, as well. Can't believe I had this same question and didn't realize the newline echo was production by default.